# eliminate rows according to logical argument

Tags: r

i have a large dataset with more than 200 000 datas.  I would like to eliminate the patients who have the FALSE statement in the rows next to them

this is how it looks like:

```
patient1  FALSE  TRUE  FALSE FALSE
patient2  TRUE   TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
Patient3  TRUE    NA   NA     NA
Patient4  FALSE   NA   NA     NA
```

this is how i want the dataset to look like

```
Patient2 TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
Patient3  TRUE  NA    NA   NA
```

Could anyone help me, please? :)

Comment: Qazaz, oyu need to make your post more readble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate all the columns to a new variable except patient column and use grepl function on whole dataset, check the code below for the same

```
     def <- data.frame(patient=c("patient1","patient2","patient3"),one=c(T,F,T),two=c(T,T,T),three=c(T,NA,NA),
          stringsAsFactors = F)

        def <- within(def,new<-paste(one,two,three))

        def <- subset(def, !grepl(F,def$new))

        def$new <- NULL

print(def)
patient  one  two three
1 patient1 TRUE TRUE  TRUE
3 patient3 TRUE TRUE    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `rowSums` as follows:

```
df[rowSums(!df[, -1], na.rm = TRUE) == 0, ]
```

Output is:

```
2 patient2 TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
3 Patient3 TRUE   NA   NA   NA
```

EDIT: Based on comments below on `row.names`, adding different option:

If the data frame is read such that the patient numbering is the names of rows instead of it's own column, you can get the result as follows:

```
df
            V2   V3    V4    V5
patient1 FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE
patient2  TRUE TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
Patient3  TRUE   NA    NA    NA
Patient4 FALSE   NA    NA    NA

df[rowSums(!df, na.rm = TRUE) == 0, ]
           V2   V3   V4   V5
patient2 TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
Patient3 TRUE   NA   NA   NA
```

Comment: hello thx for ur help. When I use this code i get an error saying: 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Here is how I read it: `df <- read.table(text = 'patient1  FALSE  TRUE  FALSE FALSE
patient2  TRUE   TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
Patient3  TRUE    NA   NA     NA
Patient4  FALSE   NA   NA     NA')`. Depends on how you are reading it.

Comment: but the dataframe i have has more than 200 000 data in it, how do I get that large data read in a way where the code i usable?

Comment: Not sure why you can't read 200,000 rows of data into R using `read.csv` or similar command. I only used the above syntax because of how you provided the sample data.

Comment: cool thx. I can read the data into R but i think its not set in a way where the code recognize the variables.

Comment: Depends....if the `patient1`, `patient2` etc. are read as row names instead of it's own column, then you will have to not do the `-1` inside my code above. If they are added as a column of it's own, then my code should work fine since it is simply removing that column by doing `-1`.

Comment: i think that might be it. What do I write instead? could u write the code again with patients as rows?

Comment: Edited and added this option. Hope that helps.